# How to register a webhook with a unique/my own name

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks

**Summary:** I want to have an wehook url with a specific name for the webhook, rather than .../custom/ or .../genericjson/ if using those nuget packages.

i.e.
https://localhost:44300/api/webhooks/incoming/MyWebhook?code=1234567890

All the guides and the likes that I've found are either for existing Webhook nuget packages (Github, bitbucket, slack etc.) or the Generic and Custom one (that I don't really understand the difference of, besides the names, but thats another matter).
I got the **genericjson** one up and running and it's doing what it is supposed to, but I would much rather have a more correct url and/or name for the Webhook.

So how do I get (which I assume is what I need to get it working as I want)

```
config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
```

to instead work as if it were

```
config.InitializeReceiveMyWebhookWebHooks();
```

and thus my server listening for webhooks on the above URL (provided I add the key in appSettings and so on).

I tried looking at the definition of **InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks()** and **InitializeReceiveGitHubWebHooks()**, but there is barely any code there nor do I know how/what/where to create my own version of it.
I'm quite new to Asp.net (have previously mostly coded sites in html/css/php/javascript on Apache, rather than Asp.net/C# on IIS) so I recon there ought to be some easy way to solve it, but after an entire day searching and trying I'm at an end as to what to try next.

**Edit:**
Currently this is what my code (related to Webhook) looks like. Nothing special, just bare minimum to get the webhook working.

**Web.config**

```xml
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_GenericJson" value="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //The revelant part to the question
        config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
    }
}
```

**GenericJsonWebHookHandler.cs**

```cs
namespace Project.API.Webhooks
{
    public class GenericJsonWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
    {
        public GenericJsonWebHookHandler()
        {
            this.Receiver = "genericjson";
        }

        public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
        {
            // Get JSON from WebHook
            JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();
            //Do something with webhook
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.

By looking at the [GitHub of AspNetWebHooks](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks) and further in to the [GenericJSON WebHook](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic) that I'm using, I finally found out what was missing.

The only thing needed was create a file called `HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs` and copy+paste the code from the [HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic/Extensions/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs) source into the newely created file and change

```
public static void InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks(this HttpConfiguration config)
```

to what I wanted it to listen to

```
public static void InitializeReceiveMyWebhookWebHooks(this HttpConfiguration config)
```

like so.

Then I also needed to create a file called `MyWebhookReceiver.cs` and copy+paste the code from [GenericJsonWebHookReceiver.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic/WebHooks/GenericJsonWebHookReceiver.cs) and change the contents slightly

```
    public class GenericJsonWebHookReceiver : WebHookReceiver
    {
        internal const string RecName = "genericjson";
```

into

```
    public class MyWebhookWebHookReceiver : WebHookReceiver
    {
        internal const string RecName = "MyWebhook";
```

It still acts like GenericJSON webhook (which is what I wanted) but now I can use `/api/incoming/MyWebhook/whateverIWant?code=123456790` as webhook URL instead of having it look like `/genericjson/MyWebhook?code=1234567890`.

You still need the handler file, but in the same way the two files were slightly changed here you can do the same with the handler. Create `MyWebHookHandler.cs` and just copy+paste the code, changing the `GenericJson` to `MyWebHook` and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work! If anyone else is following this, the only couple of thingf missing is the Web.config entry

```
<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_GenericJson" value="i=xxx,z=xxx" />
```

becomes:

```
<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_MyWebhook" value="i=xxx,z=xxx" />
```

As the last section of the key name needs to match the name of the new naming convention in the last section.

And the handler itself - on the constructor:

Should be:

```
public MyWebhookHandler() 
{ 
    this.Receiver = GenericJsonWebHookReceiver.ReceiverName; 
}
```

not:

```
public MyWebhookHandler() 
{ 
    this.Receiver = "genericjson"; 
}
```

Also - there is no benefit doing the HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs step.

You do however need to to the GenericJsonWebHookReceiver.cs step for the process to work.